# Maven Project in JBOSS, how to change priority of classloader?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, classcastexception

After reading this article:

[EAR & WAR Class Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030008/ear-and-war-class-loader)

and this artcle:

[CXF JBOSS issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201104.mbox/%3C4DA2B56B.30406@redhat.com%3E)

I am quite certain that JBOSS 4.2.3 class loader is trying to find class ServiceDelegate21 inside lib/endorsed folder but it's somehow different from class inside my EAR file and hence throws a :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl cannot
be cast to javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceDelegate21
```

Of-course everything works fine if I move the 2 jars form endorsed folder. But this is not an option.

I need to tell JBOSS 4.2.3 GA Class loader from my maven project, to look first inside my EAR and then lib/endorsed folder.

Any ideas?

[edit:]

Inside lib/endored: 
jboss-jaxws
jboss-jaxws-ext

Inside my EAR, I believe the jar tha conflicts is

jaxws-rt-2.1.7.jar

but take a look at e full jar list of my project

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post jar version in lib/endorsed  and EAR?

Comment: ok just edited u can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are mixing a lot of jars here. You have jars in Maven dependency, then jars in build path separately under `C:\eclipseHelios\lib`

Could you please clean it up, and make sure that all the required jars are either in JRE lib or Maven dependency only. For ws jar, the maven config is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I see many duplicate version of jars. e.g. jaxws-api.2.1.jar as well in maven. **The more is the duplicate, more is class version clash!**

Please clean your library and try again.

Comment: Looks like the solution is hidden in this artcle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven
there's a xml-apis jar tha I needed to remove from my maven dependencies